# Intersection of compact topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact topological space, and $(Z_n)_{n \geq 1}$ a sequence of closed subsets of $X$, and let $U \subseteq X$ be open such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty Z_i \subseteq U$.

I have to prove that there exists a positive $N$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^N Z_i \subseteq U$

How can I prove this? What kind of theorems can I use, maybe the finite intersection property?

Comment: Was there a last sentence to your post, that you intended to complete?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}Z_i\subset U$ then $U^c\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}Z_i^c$. Since $X$ is compact and $U$ is open, what can you say about $U^c$?

Comment: Is it compact aswell?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And $\{Z_i^c\}$ is an open cover of $U^c$.

Comment: That's true! Thanks for helping, this helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\bigcap_{i =1}^\infty Z_i \subseteq U$.

The $Z_i$ are closed so $Z_i^\complement$ is open in $X$ and we note that

$$\{U\} \cup \{Z_i^\complement: i =1,2\ldots \}$$ is an open cover of $X$: if $x \notin Z_i^\complement$ for all $i$, so not covered by any of the right hand sets, it's in all $Z_i$ and so in $U$, and so all $x \in X$ are in one of these sets.

Apply compactness of $X$ to get a finite subcover and let $N$ be the largest index of the $Z_i^\complement$ we use in the finite subcover.

Then an $x \in X$ that would be in $\bigcap_{i=1}^N Z_i$ but not in $U$ would not be covered by any set in that finite subcover, so such $x$ cannot exist and the desired inclusion must hold.